# json.JSONDecoder().decode() can not work well

Tags: python, json, decode

code is simple, but it can not work. I don't know the problem

```
import json

json_data = '{text: \"tl4ZCTPzQD0k|rEuPwudrAfgBD3nxFIsSbb4qMoYWA=\", key: \"MPm0ZIlk9|ADco64gjkJz2NwLm6SWHvW\"}'
my_data = json.JSONDecoder().decode(json_data)
print my_data
```

throw exption behinde:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python27\project\demo\digSeo.py", line 4, in <module>
    my_data = json.JSONDecoder().decode(json_data)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "D:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `json_data` is not valid JSON.

In JSON, property names need to be in double quotes (`"`). Also, the double quotes terminating the string values don't need to be ecaped since you're already using single quotes (`'`) for the string.

Example:

```
json_data = '{"text": "tl4ZCTPzQD0k|rEuPwudrAfgBD3nxFIsSbb4qMoYWA=", "key": "MPm0ZIlk9|ADco64gjkJz2NwLm6SWHvW"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The json module in Python standard library can work well, that's what a lot of people are using for their applications.

However these few lines of code that use this module have a small issue. The problem is that your sample data is not a valid JSON. The keys (text and key) should be quoted like this:

```
json_data = '{"text": \"tl4ZCTPzQD0k|rEuPwudrAfgBD3nxFIsSbb4qMoYWA=\", "key": \"MPm0ZIlk9|ADco64gjkJz2NwLm6SWHvW\"}'
```